# I cannot update my raspberry pi!

Tags: pi-2

```
pi@rpi:~ $ sudo apt-get install update
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/mirrordirector.raspbian.org_raspbian_dists_jessie_main_binary-armhf_Packages (1)
E: Problem opening /var/lib/apt/lists/mirrordirector.raspbian.org_raspbian_dists_jessie_contrib_binary-armhf_Packages
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Comment: What is the output of `cat /var/lib/apt/lists/mirrordirector.raspbian.org_raspbian_dists_jessie_contrib_binary-armhf_Packages`?

Answer (score 3):

You issued the wrong command here. Debian package manager works like this:

- first, you update the list of packages with `apt-get update`. This downloads a list of packages which a server currently has to a local file in `/var/lib/apt/lists/`
- second, you install/upgrade packages from that list, using `apt-get install package_name` or `apt-get upgrade`, respectively.

Your command jumps to step 2 right away and tries to install a software called `update` which presumably doesn't exist.